# AKS Azure DevOps Build Agent

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a Azure DevOps Linux Build Agent in Azure Kubernetes Service.

I created the yaml file and created the secrets to use inside of the file.

I applied the file and have "CreateContainerConfigError" with my pod in a "waiting" state.

I run command

```
"kubectl get pod <pod name> -o yaml"
```

and it states the secret "vsts" could not be found.

I find this weird because I used "kubectl get secrets" and I see the secrets "vsts-account" and "vsts-token" listed.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hello there, my apologies. I continued to work on it and looks like my issue was that I didn't reference the AZP_URL within my yaml file. I restarted my steps and added that parameter in my file and the agent was successfully deployed. Thank you for trying to help me solve the problem.

Comment: No problem, I will. I’m still fairly new to this so thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check your kubernetes configuration, which is supposed to be like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: vsts-agent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vsts-agent
        version: "0.1"
    spec:
      containers:
      – name: vsts-agent
        image: microsoft/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-18.06.1-ce-standard
        env:
          – name: VSTS_ACCOUNT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: vsts
                key: VSTS_ACCOUNT
          – name: VSTS_TOKEN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: vsts
                key: VSTS_TOKEN
          – name: VSTS_POOL
            value: dockerized-vsts-agents
        volumeMounts:
        – mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-volume
      volumes:
      – name: docker-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

You may follow the blog below to see whether it helps you:

https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/01/10/run-azure-devops-private-agents-in-kubernetes-clusters/